# Cast static void * to NSObject*

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have more constants like this one:

```
static void * MyContext = &MyContext;
```

and now I want to post an NSNotification with this context included in its userInfo dictionary, but I have problems casting it to NSObject* an putting it into an NSDictionary. I'm using __bridge for casting but I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS at runtime.

Are there some restrictions for casting void* to NSObject*? The only casting that doesn't crash is __bridge_transfer but then it crashes when adding to dictionary. I'm running out of options and thinking about dropping void* completely and use NSString* instead.

Comment: you are lying to the compiler and the runtime. Memory management will eventually try to treat it as an Objective-C object and will crash, because it's **not an object.** Don't lie to the compiler and the runtime.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Ok, then I defined extern void * const MyContext in .h and void * const MyContext = @"MyContext" in .m. Now I can put (__bridge id)context into dictionary and extract it as void * context = (__bridge void *)(notif.userInfo[@"myContext"]) from notification. Anything wrong with this solution? Would context == MyContext be a comparison problem later on?

Comment: no, that should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *cast* an arbitrary `void` pointer to `NSObject`, but you
can *wrap* it into an `NSValue` object

```
static void * MyContext = &MyContext;
NSValue *contextValue = [NSValue valueWithPointer:MyContext];
```

and retrieve the pointer later with

```
void *context = [contextValue pointerValue];
```

Alternatively, use a `NSString` object as context

```
static NSString *MyContext = @"com.company.mycontext";
```

without the need for any bridging.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, NSValue is what I was looking for. However, I just tried it and by the time I receive the notification the retrieved pointerValue is different than MyContext, can't figure out why.

Comment: @AndreiMarincas: That is strange and should not happen. Do you compare with the same `MyContext` variable everywhere, or do you have multiple static definitions in different source files?

Comment: Finally! It works if I have `extern void * MyContext` in .h and `void * MyContext = &MyContext` in .m, otherwise MyContext and &MyContext are different when I wrap the pointer in NSValue. I was having `static void * MyContext = &MyContext` in .h so I broke it into both .h and .m.